# C# WPF toggle button drag, swipe right-left

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I want to make a custom button. It's like toggle but has 3 functions. As seen in the first picture, the "PICK" circle button appears in the middle. When I swipe the circle to the right or left, it should move towards the direction I swiped and hold until the end. How can I do that?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this. One that comes to mind is to create a `mouseDown` event and then monitor the position of the mouse's x position. You can have the element's x position follow the cursor until the mouseUp or until a set max boundary on either side and, when released, you can set the value as either left, right, or back in the middle. `mouseUp` could evaluate the element's x position and determine where it should settle and what the value should be.

Comment: I struggled today and actually got to that stage, but I couldn't position it in the middle. And I don't want that direction dragging it all the way. I want it to stick directly in that direction as soon as there is a movement in that direction. It should act like Toggle. I also experimented with Blend today. https://www.loom.com/share/653e033521874562973e368ff171e502

Comment: Figure out where you want the left x to be, where you want the right x to be, and then you can meet in the middle programmatically if needed. I'd give at least *some* slide before it makes a choice because it can be finicky otherwise - something like `if(middleX - currentX > 50) { /* toggle left */ }` and `if(middleX - currentX < -50) { /* toggle right */` otherwise `/* middle */`

Comment: Have you solved the problem? Did the above method help you?

Comment: Hi @JialeXue-MSFT, Thanks for asking. No, I was not able to complete the development of the gesture function. I have developed a button as seen in the Loom video, but I need a button with the function of answering an iPhone call. The user has to swipe the circle with PICK right or left. The PICK should be positioned in the middle of the program opening. I have to trigger the Click event when the scroll is complete.

Comment: Source Code CS file (https://gist.github.com/mcyenikoylu/8ded1db02d20ece3a4c3ccb1dc08055d) XAML file (https://gist.github.com/mcyenikoylu/e19210f30335292bf3f11c3c94798165)